node.js socket.io connecting to a non http device
I am working on a system which uses C# applications and a socket to connect to remote devices, the connection is established by connecting to the IP address and a port number.  A very short plain text message is sent and requests are issued again using a short text message.
The response is also plain text.  I want to replace the applications that perform these transactions on the client side with node.js
In the node application I have installed socket.io and also socket.io-client modules, I am using node.js v21.7.1 on Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.19045
In my node application:
var socket    = require("socket.io");
var socketcli = require("socket.io-client");
...
var strTestCli = "X.X.X.X:1024";
var sckTest = socketcli.connect(strTestCli);
console.dir(sckTest);
sckTest.on("connection", objConn => {
    console.log("Connected to " + strTestCli);
    objConn.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Connected to " + strTestCli + " disconnected!");
    });
});

Obviously I have not put in the IP address, however I know the one I'm using is correct and exists.
When I dump out sckTest, the uri shows:
uri:  'undefined//X.X.X.X:1024'
...
engine: Socket {
   ...
   hostname: 'undefined',
   port: '80'

Am I completely going down the wrong route?  Can anyone help put me on the right path, can this be done with node.js ?
[Edit] I've also tried using the web socket module:
var wsCli = require("websocket").client;
...
var strTestCli = "ws://X.X.X.X:1024/";
var sckTest = new wsCli(strTestCli, 'echo-protocol');
console.dir(sckTest);
sckTest.on("connectFailed", err => {
    console.log(err);
});
sckTest.on("connect", objConn => {
    console.log("Connected to " + strTestCli);
    objConn.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Connected to " + strTestCli + " disconnected!");
    });
});

The results from dumping sckTest:
uri:  Url {
    protocol: 'ws:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: `X.X.X.X:1024`,
    port: `1024`,
    hostname: `X.X.X.X`,
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/',
    path: '/',
    href: 'ws://X.X.X.X:1024/'
}

Thank you @rveerd, implemented your suggestion and found this on the client:
https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757

socket.io are not plain TCP/IP sockets. You can use the built-in Node.js net module for TCP/IP sockets. See the documentation.

@rveerd, thank you, if you would like to post this as an answer, I will tick it and close the question.

socket.io sockets are not plain TCP/IP sockets, so this will not work.
You do not need external modules to work with plain TCP/IP sockets in Node.js. You can use the built-in net module for this.
See the documentation for details.
